# Correct way of using singleton in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton

I have a singleton class as follows

```
object SharedPrefTask {

fun doSomeWork() {
    ....
    ....
}}
```

I am using the method `doSomeWork` in 2 ways.
Approach 1

```
private var prefTask: SharedPrefTask = SharedPrefTask
prefTask.doSomeWork()
```

Approach 2

```
SharedPrefTask.doSomeWork()
```

Which is the correct approach here?

Comment: My opinion: If all you have is that `object`, then the second approach; if the `object` implements an interface, then the first approach but where the property type is explicitly made the interface type. And depending on the exact nature of that singleton and how it's used, having the interface may make more sense for testing, so that you can use a mock if and when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are technically correct and will have the same outcome. When you use your first approach `prefTask: SharedPrefTask = SharedPrefTask` all you're really doing is making a variable that references the object. So if you were to call `prefTask.doSomeWork()` it would be the exact same as calling `SharedPrefTask.doSomeWork()`.

Knowing this, it seems like it would be best to just go with your second approach since it is more clear and uses less code.